# Missing PdfSharp library reference in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, pdfsharp

I added the PdfSharp library via the Nuget Package Manager(so I do not have to manually add the project) and I can see the package has been successfully installed. However, when I try to reference the library, I get errors in my code on the following lines:

```
using PdfSharp;
using PdfSharp.Drawing;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;
```

I then expanded the References folder and noticed that there's no reference to the PdfSharp library that had been added. I have tried deleting and adding the package several times but no changes.

Is this a Xamarin Studio thing?

Comment: Do you have more than on project in your solution? You may added it in the wrong one

Comment: @Sharky no I only have one project. I was able to get to the bottom of it and I've posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I had to manually add the reference. So I clicked on **References** --> **Edit References** --> **Browse** --> navigated to the packages folder in the project file --> Look for the PdfSharp package file and select the **PdfSharp.dll file**. This reference will then be added into the project.

Comment: any luck after adding PdfSharp.dll..
I mean, with .dll I fixed namespace resolution, but when I compile I get System.Windows.Forms library missing in Droid project?

Have any one integrated this library for Forms?